# What was the secret?

Tags: lateral-thinking

Bob, Jane and I keep the same secret. No one else in the world knows except for the three of us. One day, I told the secret to someone outside of us three. Still, no one else in the world knows except for Bob, Jane and I. What was the secret? (Hint:This is not a language or naming trick)

Answer (score 2):

The secret is

> Trick question! The secret is irrelevant. The pronoun of "us" naturally comes to include the new participant, making the final statement hold true.

Comment: I improved the language. But, your solution made sense

Answer (score 1):

While I think the actual answer is probably more clever,
The secret could be:

> How to travel to other worlds
> So, you could tell someone the secret, but
>  No one in *this* world, outside the original three, knows

Comment: Good try. I dont know whether to say its a little more clever or a little more stupid.

Answer (score 0):

The Secret is:

> **No one else in the world knows except for us**!

Comment: Is that a secret? feels like a statement

Comment: Well if that was the secret, that would be correct. But, “I” can confirm it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The secret could be:

> "We three are brothers" 
>  So we three know, but the outsider doesn't know who they(rest of the three 
>  except me) are,
>  So he is half kept on secret and only we three know it complete.

Comment: Hint: its a trick question

Answer (score 0):

I and my two friends are all the same physical person.  I have multiple personality disorder.  One day, a fourth personality emerged and he/she is now in on the secret!  This reminds me of the movie "Split" that came out last year.

Answer (score 0):

The secret is;

> Three of us know it!

explanation

> originally three people know the secret, when you tell it to another person, he/she includes in us(four people in us) but only three of us knows it(secret itself) and no one except us knows it(makes this statement true as well). so doesn't matter how many includes in us but both the statements will be true always.

Answer (score -1):

The secret known among those three is

> This is secret. Do not tell to anybody!